# Trouble with "dotnet run seeddata" when trying to seed a database with EntityFrameworkCore. Specifically with ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been following along with Teddy Smith's ASP.NET Core 6 Web API (although I am using .NET 8.0 since the video is a little old) and `PokemonReviewApp` is the name of the project (some might be familiar with it). I have come to the part where I have been trying to properly install Entity Framework and get the `DbContext` seeding into a database. Please help.

Using ASP.NET Core 6 Web API in Visual Studio 2022. I have created a bunch of models, defined a connection string to a SQL Server database on my machine and have that reflected in the `Appsettings.json`. I also thought I had all the correct frameworks installed via the NuGet Package Manager Console (`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, Design, etc etc.)

The 1st time I had this, it seeded the database inside SQL correctly. I was able to select the top 1000 rows from each table that was pulled in and saw the data for each row. That information was in the Seed.cs file, and it was copy/pasted from Teddy Smith's github for this specific project. These were the instructions in the video.

Although that part was successful, I was never able to get the SwaggerUI the pop open in the browser when I would debug the solution. This was my only problem. I troubleshooted for a while, gave up..and decided to start from scratch. I deleted the project solution and the database inside Microsoft SQL Server.

Now after going through the program again, I am getting errors when using the Terminal in VS2022 for `dotnet run seeddata`.

By the point, I have already used Package Manager Console to run `Add-Migration InitialCreate`. That command runs successfully; I then do `Update-Database` and that was successful, too. However when I open the terminal in VS2022, and type `dotnet run seedddata`, it doesn't work.

The error is long, but this is part of it :

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
> An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'PokemonReviewApp.Data.DataContext'.
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Name', table 'pokemonreview.dbo.Owners'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.

Any and all help would be appreciated; apologies for not explaining it well.

I was hoping to get the SwaggerUI to pop open in the browser when I would debug the project solution. (PokemonReviewApp ASP.NET Core Web API)

Comment: by any chance did you looked into the data which is being seeded ? to me error message is clear that some column is not allowed to have NULL. may be there is missing data.

Comment: If you can provide a minimal reproducible example, including both the C# code and the project file, 
we're much more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: Here is a link to my github for this project. https://github.com/jcthom114/PokemonReviewApp

Add-Migration InitialCreate and then Update-Database works in the Package Manager Console, however the data isn't seeded correctly. When I go to SQL and that database, no information is in the rows; it just has the field IDs.

All of my Nuget Packages are up to date.

Comment: I deleted the database is SSMS, created a new one and established a connection string in VS2022. After Add-Migration InitialCreate and then Update-Database, I execute dotnet run seeddata in the terminal console. It says build started but it never does anything other than display a section of code and no obvious error messages in it, and never says succeeded. 
Anyway, I run the program now w/o debugging and it actually pulls up the swaggerUI in the browser, but it says "No Operations defined in the spec"
Any idea what this is about? Not really sure how else to explain it. Check out my Github

Comment: From your project you don't have Controllers folder, so  it says "No Operations defined in the spec" .Try to add a controller and some actions to see.

Comment: Ok, I created a Controllers folder and then right clicked it, Add -> New Scaffolding Item. From there, I select 'API Controller with actions, using Entity Framework'. After that, how do I know which API Controllers with Actions to Add to the options. 
Model Class I chose DataContextSnapshot (PokemonReview.App.Migrations)
DBContext Class I chose DataContext (PokemonReviewApp.Data
Controller Name - DataContextModelSnapContrrollers. 
I Get an error after trying to do this
DB Context Class